# Wpf data grid not showing items when window is opened for the first time

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

In my wpf application I have a data grid whose items source is bound to an observable collection. items in the collection are loaded using an async task. If  the window is opened for the first time it is not showing any data in the grid, but blank rows and if a close and re-open the window it is showing data in the grid. Anybody know why it is happenning. here is my code.

```
<DataGrid
        x:Name="dtg"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False"
        RowHeight="35"
        CanUserResizeColumns="False"
        CanUserResizeRows="False"
        CanUserSortColumns="True"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DepartmentId}" Header="Slno" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DepartmentName}" Header="Department" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

this is the code for loading items to the observable collection and it is just a call to another method

```
 private async void loadData() {
        Departments = await _dataManager.getDepartmentsAsync();
    }
```

I've been trying to fix it for more than 30 minutes. Anybody know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an `onPropertyChanged` call to the setter of the observable collection and everything is working as expected

```
public ObservableCollection<Department> Departments {
        get { return _departments; }
        set {
            _departments = value;
            onPropertyChanged(nameof(Departments));
        }
    }
```